# How to display a div in a post in your category page - wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

I have a website where each post is displayed and each post has a description explaining the post.

How can I get my category page (the page that summarises all posts) to show only the small summary of the post and nothing else. At the moment I am using

```
the_excerpt();
```

but this limits the text to 55 words, however some are smaller than that, and so other text is displayed in the category that I don’t want.

For example, this is an example post: 
http://thestudentbubble.com/hidden-gems/hidden-gems-restaurants/ganges-indian/

As you can see below the description is additional information which I don't want it to appear on the category page.

this is the category page - http://thestudentbubble.com/hidden-gems/hidden-gems-restaurants/

yet the additional information that I don't want to appear still appears.

The text I want to appear is in:

```
<div class = "bioText">
```

How can I make only the text in the div appear in the category page? 
Thank you for the help!

this is the category loop :

```
<div class="comment">   
                    <?php
                        $cats = get_the_category();
                        $category_id = $cats[0]->cat_ID;
                        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category' => $category_id);
                        $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
                        foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :

                        $this_post_ID = get_the_ID();
                        $this_post_preview = get_post_meta( $this_post_ID, 'post_preview', true );
                        echo $this_post_preview;

                        //the_excerpt();
                         //the_content();
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        endforeach; 

                     ?>



                </div>
```

Comment: You could workaround the issue by creating a custom textarea field in each post, pass its content in the metadata, and then print it. Suppose you'd like to preview only this sentence: "Our favourite Indian in Exeter. Great quality food with a sophisticated layout." You'd just type it in the field, and then it would appear in the preview. No extra text, no hassles. If you wish to proceed this way, I can give you more help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - yes I would like to try it you way. how do i create a custom text area field?

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, the first thing to do is to create a custom textarea in each post's admin panel. It will appear under the editor. Let's create the .php file that will contain our code, call it post_preview_field.php, and place it in the theme root folder. After doing that, we will need to reference it in our functions.php file. This is done by simply adding the following line:

```
require_once(get_template_directory().'/post_preview_field.php');
```

Let's open our post_preview_field.php file and write the code.

```
<?php
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'post_preview_metabox' );
    add_action( 'save_post', 'post_preview_save_postdata' );

function post_preview_metabox() {
$screens = array( 'post' );
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
        'post_preview_metabox_id',
        __( 'Post Preview', 'post_preview_textdomain'),
        'post_preview_inner_boxes',
        $screen
    );
}
}

function post_preview_inner_boxes( $post ) {
wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'post_preview_noncename' );
$post_preview_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_preview', true );
echo '<label for="post_preview_new_field">';
    _e("", 'post_preview_textdomain' );
?>
</label>
<textarea name="post_preview_new_field" id="post_preview_new_field" ><?php echo  $post_preview_value; ?></textarea>

<?php }

function post_preview_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
if ( 'post' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return;
} else {}
if ( ! isset( $_POST['post_preview_noncename'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['post_preview_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
return;
$post_ID = $_POST['post_ID'];
$post_preview = ( $_POST['post_preview_new_field'] );
add_post_meta($post_ID, 'post_preview', $post_preview, true) or
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'post_preview', $post_preview);
}

?>
```

Here we go. We just created a textarea field that appears in every post's panel, can contain some text, is saved every time we save\update the post and is stored in the post's metadata.

Now, all we have to do is access this value in the frontend and echo it. How do we do that?
In the loop, we first assign the post ID to a variable:

```
$this_post_ID = get_the_ID();
```

and then assign the data we stored to another:

```
$this_post_preview = get_post_meta( $this_post_ID, 'post_preview', true );
```

That's it. We can now echo the preview:

```
echo $this_post_preview;
```

Comment: I'm already stuck at the first hurdle. I went onto appearance -> Editor. Yet I can't seem to find a button to create a new php file. Any help here?

Comment: an I can't seem to find the theme root folder either - am  I looking in te wrong place?

Comment: Where do you have WordPress installed? Is it in a local installation on your computer, or is it online?

Comment: wp is installed online

Comment: so i created a php file with the given text and added it onto the server online - but how do I get it into the theme root folder I have a theme folder, but not a root folder :/

Comment: That's the folder! The path should be something like wp-content /themes/your_theme. You should have a functions.php file in it. Add require_once(get_template_directory().'/post_preview_field.php'); to it or, if it doesn't exist, create a new file and paste <?php require_once(get_template_directory().'/post_preview_field.php'); ?> in it. Now, going in the template admin and opening a post, you should see the new textarea.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help - I have got ithalf working, I hae the preview post, however the description seems to be the same for all even though I added different ones - maybe theres something with my loop. I have added my loop in the question above.

Comment: Let's first understand if the problem is in the post_preview_field.php file or in the loop. In the admin panel, every post has its specific preview or they are all the same? If they're all the same, there's an error in the post_preview_field.php. If they're not, the problem's in the loop.

Comment: they has a specific post preview - the post previews are all different for each post. so i think it's in the loop

Comment: Mmm, I just noticed that you're loading the posts with a foreach loop. Try and change the value of the this_post_ID variable to this:

$this_post_ID = $post ->ID;

Comment: changed it , but still no change :/ still shows the post preview the same for all of them.. it shows the very first post preview for all

Comment: Try to remove the wp_reset_postdata(); line from the foreach loop.

Comment: already tried that lol - tried several things but wasnt workign - so I went with the answer above, Thank you for your help!!! I got there in the end :))

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by adding

```
<!--more-->
```

after each of the descriptions.